# How to run Apache ant in offline mode?

Tags: ant

In the project's build.xml there is this line:
`<target name="resolve" depends="init-x" unless="offline">`

But how to enable the offline mode?

Neither the online documentation nor ant's manpage mentions the "offline" mode.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation doesn't mention an offline mode because there is no offline mode in Ant. Whoever wrote your build file made it sensitive to the existence of a property named `offline`.

Your build file contains a target that uses the `unless` attribute. This means the target will not be executed if an Ant property with the name `offline` exists.

When running Ant from the command line you can set it via `-Doffline=foo`. Note the value of the property doesn't matter for Ant's `unless` attribute, so `-Doffline=false` will still mean your target will be skipped.